# Relationship async load Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-identity

I have these two classes:

*Department*

```
public string Id{ get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

*Post*

```
public string Id{ get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to load `department` with

```
var dep = await _db.Departments.FindAsync("someid");
```

now I want to get the first item with async:

```
var post = await dep.FirstAsync(s=>s.Name==name);
```

`FirstAsync` does not exists?

and the second problem I have is to implement custom Identity, and trying to load a user with `FindAsync`, but it doesn't exists. I use: `var user = await _db.Users.FindAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId())`, and it doesn't contain the `FindAsync` function but `FirstAsync` and `Find` exists.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a FirstAsync method. You are awaiting the result of FindAsync() when you assign it to the dep variable. You can just use the synchronous First().

Comment: but in interface i've load some elements async, with loading animations, its simple example, what i need

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the second FirstAsync because your object is a department. Your first statement awaits a FindAsync method. The FindAsync method starts a task of type Task. If you await that task it results in a Department. So you might want to specify an exact type for your first statement to clarify that:

```
Department dep = await _db.Departments.FindAsync("someid");
```

FirstAsync is a method for IQueryables. Your department is not an IQueryable so you cannot use it. You will specifically need to refer to the Posts collection if you want a post (image that your department class has many different collections). The Posts collection does not have asynchronous methods however. You could use the .AsQueryable() method to convert it to a queryable and then use FindAsync.

However if the post is all you are interested in you can also write it in a single LINQ query and have the database find the related items:

```
string postName = "...";
string depId = "..."";

var postQuery =
    from post in _db.Posts
    where post.Name == postName && post.Department.Id == depId
    select post;

var post = postQuery.FirstAsync();
```